# opencv stdin from subprocess

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run a subprocess command, capture the stdout and pipe that into opencv. I found an example using numpy, and I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it... I haven't had any luck so far. Here is where I am:

```
result = subprocess.run(["gphoto2", "--capture-movie", "--stdout"], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

array = numpy.frombuffer(result.stdout, dtype='uint8')
img = cv2.imdecode(array, 1)
cv2.imshow("window", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

It's almost as if it gets hung on the first step - does it have to be pushed to a thread so it can move on to the next portion?